# Where do I put my helper functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

In Meteor, I put a helper function:

`Template.list.sessID_Gen = function(){... };` in `myapp.js`, because when I tried to place it in `lib/main.js`, any subsequent calls to that helper function in `myapp.js` reported that the function did not exist (The full traceback is here: http://ideone.com/fljXJM).

So, what would be the correct way to get this function out of the business side of my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps of any non-trivial size should organize themselves per the docs, with `client`, `lib` and `server` folders, among others. Then the most common design pattern is to create one HTML and one JavaScript file per template, so:

- **client/list.html** would contain your "list" template, i.e. `<template name="list">...`
- **client/list.js** would contain the helpers for "list", i.e. `Template.list.sessID_Gen...`

See also https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#where-should-i-put-my-files